# Managing unsupported transaction attribute in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish

I need to annotate a message-driven bean with transaction attribute NEVER

```
@TransactionAttribute(value=NEVER)
```

and deploy the enterprise application to many application servers. Unfortunately one of them (Glassfish 3.1.2) does not accept/support such attribute

```
Invalid transaction attribute for message-driven bean
```

That bean is never used when running inside Glassfish, but it must be part of the codebase. To work around the unsupported attribute, it can be annotated with

```
@TransactionAttribute(value=NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

My question is: how could I possibily manage this when building a release ? I thought about a "brute force" method: keep two versions of the MDB.java file (one as default and one for Glassfish), then call the build procedure twice, replacing the .java file each time. But would there be a smarter way ?

Comment: What build tool do you use?

Comment: NetBeans with ant-based build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it doesn't make sense to use transaction attribute `NEVER` for a message driven bean because MDBs do not have clients. Here is an extract from the EJB 3.2 specification:

> For a message-driven bean’s message listener methods (or interface), only the REQUIRED and NOT_SUPPORTED transaction attributes may be used.

Otherwise, you could override `@TransactionAttribute(value=NEVER)` with the deployment descriptor. The pseodocode looks like the following:

```
<ejb-jar>
    ...
    <assembly-descriptor>
    ...
        <container-transaction>
            <method>
                 <ejb-name>here_mdb_name</ejb-name>
                 <method-name>onMessage</method-name>
            </method>
            <trans-attribute>NotSupported</trans-attribute>
        </container-transaction>
        ..
    </assembly-descriptor>

</ejb-jar>
```

and use the build tool to copy the descriptor file into the `META-INF` folder of the jar file. This should work because the settings in the deployment descriptor override the ones in the annotations.

Comment: All right, it was an old implementation so I ditched the MDB moving its code to @Asynchronous methods. In any case OK for _ujulu_ suggestion.